# fisheye distortion and codeflower

Tags: svg, d3.js, visualization, fisheye

I have successfully implemented a codeflower view for a sample dataset. The code used to achieve that is:

```
var currentCodeFlower;
var createCodeFlower = function(json) {
    document.getElementById('jsonData').value = JSON.stringify(json);
    if(currentCodeFlower) currentCodeFlower.cleanup();
    var total = countElements(json);
    //console.log(total);
    w = parseInt(Math.sqrt(total) * 50, 10);
    h = parseInt(Math.sqrt(total) * 50, 10);
    currentCodeFlower = new CodeFlower("#visualization",w,h).update(json);
};
d3.json('data.json', createCodeFlower);
```

I now wish to add a fisheye distortion to this visualization and am not sure how to go about this. I have looked into the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye) of fisheye but as I used codeflower.js I am not sure how to access the svg element anymore. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a fish-eye distortion using a SVG filter (feDisplacement) but you need a very specific displacement map to achieve it. This is an example I wrote based on Inkscape's reference image for fisheye distortion. See other examples for how to express this in D3 syntax.

```
<filter id="trilight" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
  <feImage xlink:href="http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/images/FILTERS/bubble.png" result="lightMap" x="30" y="0" width="600" height="600"/>

<feDisplacementMap in2="lightMap" in="SourceGraphic" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="10"> 
</feDisplacementMap>

</filter>
```