# SVG feDisplacementMap filter with Mesh Distortion. possible?

Tags: javascript, svg, filter, warp

I'm trying to use a SVG `feDisplacementMap` filter combined with a mesh of control points to warp SVG elements.
This is the effect I am going for [warp image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTMqj.jpg)

Is this possible or do the limitations of feDisplacementMap make it impossible?

I have found a codepen that can do something very similar using a beziermap instead of control points. But is this proof of concept? or am I missing something and it's still impossible?

https://codepen.io/DirkWeber/pen/zYZjwwN

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/unixpickle/feDisplacementMaps or https://codepen.io/DirkWeber/pen/zYZjwwN or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824088/fisheye-distortion-and-codeflower/28826058#28826058

Comment: You can do this with a displacement map, but generating the displacement map is a *hard* programming problem. I have worked with SVG filters for over ten years and I've only come across three people who were able to generate displacement maps effectively: Dirk Weber, Zoltan Fegyver (pseudonym?) and this unixpickle fellow. I have tried several times to generate maps without success.